# Can trouble codes P2138 & P2279 be related for a 2005 Honda Pilot?

Tags: honda, acceleration, pilot

My 2005 Honda Pilot is having an issue where it loses power and the check engine light and several other lights appear at the same time. If I were to stop the car and cut it off and back on it will work fine. The issue happens a few times a week and may happen multiple times on one drive. See code definitions below. I have seen P2138 before and have replaced the Pedal Position Sensor on another Honda. It's easy. It seems like there would be some connection between the 2 issues since they showed up at the same time.

Is it possible there is a connection between the 2 issues? If so what is the relationship?

P2279 Intake Air System Leak
http://www.obd-codes.com/p2279

P2138 Throttle/Pedal Pos Sensor Voltage Correlation DTC
http://www.obd-codes.com/p2138

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can trouble codes P2138 & P2279 be related for a 2005 Honda Pilot?** Yes, it would seem so. After replacing the Pedal Position Sensor both codes went away and have not come back.

I ended up replacing the Pedal Position Sensor a few months back. Since then I noticed the car drives better and I have not seen any of the previous issues since. Replacing the Pedal Position Sensor resolved the issue.

The below forum thread describes how to replace the part on a honda accord. It is the same although the part number is different.

http://www.driveaccord.net/forums/15-7th-generation/35469-p2138-code-accelerator-position-sensor-control-arm-unrelated.html#post544361

Comment: Thanks for following up! It's great when someone can answer their own question :D

Answer (score 1):

I would think it quite possibly could be connected, but there is no guarantee here. You'll want to start with the easy (ie: easy = *no $$*) fixes first, then move to replacing parts.

Your best bet is to do a thorough check of the intake system to ensure there isn't an intake air system leak. The check is easy (but finding the leak may be difficult). Your looking for a crack, break, or leaking at a joint of the air tract *after the Mass Air Flow (MAF) sensor*. This is the metered air portion of the intake.

Next, examine the pig tail at the throttle. Look for corrosion at the connector or breakage of the wires leading up to the connector.

The OBDII link you provided says to do the following:

> - The first thing to do is go online and get the TSBs (technical service bulletins) for you vehicle relating to the code. These TSBs result from customer complaints or recognized problems and the factory recommended repair procedure.
> - Check online or in a service manual for a possible relearn procedure to reset the computer. For example, on a Nissan, turn the ignition on and wait 3 seconds. Within the next 5 seconds depress and release the pedal 5 times. Wait 7 seconds, press, and hold the pedal for 10 seconds. When the check engine light begins to blink, release the pedal. Wait 10 seconds and depress the pedal again for 10 seconds and release. Turn the ignition off.
> - Pull the electrical connector out of the throttle body. Inspect it closely for missing or bent female terminals. Look for corrosion. Clean any corrosion using a small pocket screwdriver. Place a small amount of electrical grease on the terminals and reconnect it.
> - If the terminal connector has bent or missing pins you can pick up a new "pigtail" at most auto parts stores or from the dealer. Inspect the top cover on the throttle body for cracks or warping. If any are present, call the dealer and ask if they sell just the top cover. If not, replace the throttle body.
> - With a voltmeter, probe the accelerator pedal sensor. It will have 5 volts for reference and next to it a varying signal. Turn the key on and slowly depress the pedal. The voltage should climb from .5 to 5.0 smoothly. Replace it if the voltage spikes or it has no voltage at the signal wire.
> - Look online for wire terminal identification on the throttle body of your vehicle. Probe the throttle body connector for power to the throttle motor. Have a helper turn the key on and slightly depress the pedal. If no power is present, the computer is at fault. If there is power the throttle body is malfunctioning.

If all else fails, replace the parts you deem necessary. This could be the pedal *or* the throttle body itself. When the parts are replaced, make sure you clear the codes.